# Map text files with different formatting to dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have a lot of text files which are filled with different kinds of log messages though not more than one type of message can appear per file.

> File1: (I);2017-01-12;16:54:45;Random Text;Other Text
>   File2:
>   (I);2017-01-13 15:34:56;Again Text;One More Time  //i.e.  space 
>   between date and time

I already got this to work but I want to ask if this is the "correct" way to do it. Also my method only works if the changes between semicolons and spaces always appear in the same position.
Any advice on this matter is appreciated since I am new to scala / spark.

```
//read file
val df = spark.read.textFile(file.path).filter(f => f.nonEmpty && f.length > 1 && f.startsWith("("))
//create empty dataset of type OutputMessage
var df3 = Seq.empty[OutputMessage].toDS()
//get number of semicolons within first line of the dataset to determine type
val message_type = df.take(1).mkString(",").count(_ == ';')

if(message_type == 5){
    //split by semicolon and create dataset of type InputMessage
    var df2 = df.map(x => x.split(";")).map(x => InputMessage(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5)))
    //map to dataset of type output message
    df3 = df2.map(
      x =>
        OutputMessage(x.status,
          x.messages_datestring,
          x.messages_timestring,
          x.device,
          x.device_fullmessage,
          x.device_message,
          fileName,
          getWeekday(x.messages_datestring),
          (x.messages_datestring + "T" + x.messages_timestring),
          data_company,
          data_location,
          data_systemname)
    )
  }
  else if (message_type == 4){
    var df2 = df.map(x => x.split(";")).map(x => InputMessage1(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)))
    df3 = df2.map(
      x=>
        OutputMessage(x.status,
          x.messages_datetimestring.split(" ").take(1).mkString(","),
          x.messages_datetimestring.split(" ").takeRight(1).mkString(","),
          x.device,
          x.device_fullmessage,
          x.device_message,
          fileName,
          getWeekday(x.messages_datetimestring.split(" ").take(1).mkString(",")),
          x.messages_datetimestring.replace(' ', 'T'),
          data_company,
          data_location,
          data_systemname)
    )
  }
//convert to rdd
val dsToRDD = df3_filtered.rdd
//laod to elasticsearch
dsToRDD.saveToEs("abdata/log")
```

EDIT: I just saw that some files have inconsitencies between lines. That means my solution is not really applicable anymore

EDIT: Changed it to line based execution. Most things work so far except for random seperators within the row. I get an output for this case but not the wanted.

```
  object MapRawData{
  def mapRawLine (line: String): Option[RawMessage] ={
    var msgtype = 0;
    val fields = line.split(";")
    if (fields(0).length == 3 && fields(1).length == 10) msgtype = 1
    if (fields(0).length == 3 && fields(1).length > 10) msgtype = 3
    if (fields(0).length > 16) msgtype = 2
    try {
      fields.map(_.trim)
      Some(
        RawMessage(
          status = fields(0).take(3),
          messages_datestring = if(msgtype == 1) fields(1) else if(msgtype == 2) fields(0).drop(4).take(10) else fields(1).take(10),
          messages_timestring = if(msgtype == 1) fields(2).take(8) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(0).drop(15).take(8) else (fields(1).drop(11).take(8)),
          device = if(msgtype == 1) fields(3) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(1) else fields(2),
          device_fullmessage = if(msgtype == 1) fields(4) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(2) else fields(3),
          device_message = if(msgtype == 1) fields(5) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(3) else fields(4)
        )
      )
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        println(s"Unable to parse line: $line")
        None
    }
  }
}
```

Is this variation way more time/resource consuming than the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed it to line based execution. Most things work so far except for random seperators within the row. I get an output for this case but not the wanted.

```
object MapRawData{
  def mapRawLine (line: String): Option[RawMessage] ={
    var msgtype = 0;
    val fields = line.split(";")
    if (fields(0).length == 3 && fields(1).length == 10) msgtype = 1
    if (fields(0).length == 3 && fields(1).length > 10) msgtype = 3
    if (fields(0).length > 16) msgtype = 2
    try {
      fields.map(_.trim)
      Some(
        RawMessage(
          status = fields(0).take(3),
          messages_datestring = if(msgtype == 1) fields(1) else if(msgtype == 2) fields(0).drop(4).take(10) else fields(1).take(10),
          messages_timestring = if(msgtype == 1) fields(2).take(8) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(0).drop(15).take(8) else (fields(1).drop(11).take(8)),
          device = if(msgtype == 1) fields(3) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(1) else fields(2),
          device_fullmessage = if(msgtype == 1) fields(4) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(2) else fields(3),
          device_message = if(msgtype == 1) fields(5) else if (msgtype == 2) fields(3) else fields(4)
        )
      )
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        println(s"Unable to parse line: $line")
        None
    }
  }
}
```